# CodeIgniter Shopping Cart Class: How to retrieve independent values on an array?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, mixpanel

So I have this controller using CodeIgniter's Shopping Cart Class on an e-commerce website.

It's working fine. It loads the class, adds products to cart, goes to checkout and completes the transaction. But I need to retrieve some information (such as product name, ID, price) when the user is at the checkout to send it to `Mixpanel` (which is an analytics tool).

I've added to my checkout controller this code:

```
// Sends subscription information to mixpanel
$this->mixpanel_wrapper->people_set($aluno[0]->aluno_id, array(
        '$first_name'    =>    $student[0]->student_first_name,
        '$last_name'     =>    $student[0]->student_last_name,
        '$email'         =>    $student[0]->student_email,
        ));
$this->mixpanel_wrapper->identify($student[0]->student_id);
$this->mixpanel_wrapper->track_something('Added to cart',  array ($this->cart->contents()));
// Ends mixpanel
```

It works. In my dashboard I see that a specific user activated the event "Added to Cart". But in the properties of this event I see something like this (the "property" number is added automatically by mixpanel:

```
Property: 0
{"ee55c5260c7d5fe7fe9bc73b0e0cc82c":{"name":"Product 1","price":"99.00","qty":"1","rowid":"ee55c5260c7d5fe7fe9bc73b0e0cc82c","id":"8","subtotal":99,"options":{"category":"business","teacher":"La Gracia","image":"cozinhando.png","type":"course","description":"Montar uma apresentação é como cozinhar. Se você faz um “catadão” e coloca tudo na panela, sem ordem ou critério, sai uma gororoba. Uma experiência saborosa exige cuidado e atenção na seleção e preparo dos ingredientes. Nesse curso, aprenda"}},"1bebb39e8f44062ff10639f452ea8f8f":{"name":"Product 2","price":"59.00","qty":"1","rowid":"1bebb39e8f44062ff10639f452ea8f8f","id":"7","subtotal":59,"options":{"category":"creativity","teacher":"Pedro Maciel Guimarães","image":"cover_almodovar.png","type":"course","description":"Conheça a evolução das obras de Almodóvar por duas matrizes únicas: a imitação e o intercâmbio de gêneros. Passando por suas comédias e dramas, veremos como Almodóvar pensou e produziu seus diversos trabalhos, desde suas primeiras referências"}}}
```

There were 2 items on this cart. The "product 1" and "product 2". But in fact I should see something like this:

```
Property: 0
Name: Product 1
Price: 99.00
Qty: 1
ID: 8

Property: 1
Name: Product 2
Price: 59.00
Qty: 1
ID: 7
```

What Mixpanel needs is that I convert it into an array like this one to set a new user:

```
$this->mixpanel_wrapper->people_set($aluno[0]->aluno_id, array(
    '$first_name'       => $aluno[0]->aluno_primeiro_nome,
    '$last_name'        => $aluno[0]->aluno_sobrenome,
    '$email'            => $aluno[0]->aluno_email,
));
```

Anybody knows how can I retrieve specific data from the CI's Shopping Cart Class? Something like this:

```
$this->mixpanel_wrapper->track_something('User Logged In', array(
    'Name'             => $this->cart->contents->name,
    'Product ID'       => $this->cart->contents->id,
    'Price'            => $this->cart->contents->price,
    'Quantity'         => $this->cart->contents->qty,
));
```

I think it might be really simple, but I'm stucked here (again).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be not much different than when you [display the cart](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/cart.html#displaying-the-cart).  Loop through the cart array, `$this->cart->contents()`, and handle each item.

```
foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $item)
{
    $this->mixpanel_wrapper->track_something('User Logged In', array(
        'Name'             => $item['name'],
        'Product ID'       => $item['id'],
        'Price'            => $item['price'],
        'Quantity'         => $item['qty'],
    ));
}
```

Otherwise, loop through the cart and create a new array that Mixpanel can properly handle.